# WPF Animation not Firing

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, mvvm, datagrid

All I have the following `DataGrid`

```
<DataGrid x:Name="resourceDataGrid" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
          GridLinesVisibility="None"
          RowHeaderWidth="0" 
          CanUserAddRows="True" 
          CanUserDeleteRows="True" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Resources, 
                                Mode=TwoWay,
                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                                IsAsync=True}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource readOnlyCellUpdatedStyle}"  IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <!--<DataGridTextColumn Header="KeyIndex" Binding="{Binding KeyIndex}" IsReadOnly="True"/>--> <- What I did have...
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="FileName" Binding="{Binding FileName}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ResourceName" Binding="{Binding ResourceName}" IsReadOnly="False"/>
        <controls:CollectionTextColumn Collection="ResourceStringList" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

when a row in the data set is removed I want to re-number the `KeyIndex` column. When this renumbering takes place I want to elegantly flash the updated cells letting the user know then these values were updated.

I have created the following `DataTemplate`

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="readOnlyCellUpdatedStyle">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding KeyIndex, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.SourceUpdated">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" 
                                                Duration="0:0:0.3"
                                                From="White" 
                                                To="Red" 
                                                RepeatBehavior="3x" 
                                                AutoReverse="True"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

The binding still works for the `KeyIndex` but when I update the `KayIndex` values from the ViewModel now animation occurs the value just changes. **Why is the animation not firing when the `KeyIndex` is updated?**

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use `NotifyOnTargetUpdated` and `Binding.TargetUpdated`. And don't forget to set a Background value first or animating the color will throw an exception.

- `Binding.SourceUpdated` Element -> Object
- `Binding.TargetUpdated` Object -> Element

It can get very confusing sometimes

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="readOnlyCellUpdatedStyle">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding KeyIndex, Mode=TwoWay,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" 
                                    Duration="0:0:0.3"
                                    From="White" 
                                    To="Red" 
                                    RepeatBehavior="3x" 
                                    AutoReverse="True"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: That's quality, right of the bat. Now I have the issue that this is updating when the data is first loaded into the `DataGrid` any idea how to prevent this?

Comment: I will have to some how restrict the `OnPropertyChangedEvent` when the data is loaded. I am also getting the animation occur now when I scroll the grid presumably due to the virtualisation. Is this something I can prevent from occurring in XAML? I only want to animate when the KeyIndex is changed by the ViewModel. Again, thanks for your help...

Comment: It may be a better option to create a derived `DataGridTextColumn` with the features you need built in, as using `TargetUpdated` will be pretty much impossible if you are using `Virtualization`. But if you made a custom `DataGridTextColumn` you should be able to get it working

Comment: Sorry to be a pain here, I have never created a custom control in WPF before, can you provide any decent references (that you know to be good) to get me started? Thanks very much.