# How to Create a Custom DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls, wpfdatagrid

All, in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18136371/626442 to a previous question, the answer provided a solution to the problem of my animation not firing. The code was

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="readOnlyCellUpdatedStyle">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding KeyIndex, Mode=TwoWay,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" 
                                    Duration="0:0:0.3"
                                    From="White" 
                                    To="Red" 
                                    RepeatBehavior="3x" 
                                    AutoReverse="True"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

This fires the animation when I update the `KeyIndex` column via the ViewModel. However, I only want the animation of the cells of the `DataGridTextColumn` to animate when the values are updated but they also fire when the `DataGrid` is scrolled. I was suggested

> It may be a better option to create a derived `DataGridTextColumn` with the features you need built in, as using `TargetUpdated` will be pretty much impossible if you are using Virtualization. But if you made a custom `DataGridTextColumn` you should be able to get it working.

**How do I create a custom/derived `DataGridTextColumn (I have access to blend too)?**

I have no idea how to do this and the documentation on this particular concept is sparse.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out to be quite difficult to get this working with `Virtualization` when using `VirtualizationMode="Recycling"`

I found a way to get it working by deriving `TextBlock` and attaching to the `PropertyChanged` event of the bound object.

When the value changes the animation is played, but if you scroll the recycled item does not continue to play the animation.

This is a pretty rough example but I am sure you can clean up and modify to your needs.

TextBlock:

```
public class VirtualizingNotifyTextBlock : TextBlock
{
    private INotifyPropertyChanged _dataItem;
    private string _propertyName;

    public VirtualizingNotifyTextBlock()
        : base()
    {
        this.TargetUpdated += NotifyTextBlock_TargetUpdated;
    }

    public static readonly RoutedEvent PropertyChangedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("PropertyChanged", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(VirtualizingNotifyTextBlock));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NotifyDurationProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("NotifyDuration", typeof(int), typeof(VirtualizingNotifyTextBlock), new PropertyMetadata(300));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NotifyRepeatProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("NotifyRepeat", typeof(int), typeof(VirtualizingNotifyTextBlock), new PropertyMetadata(3));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NotifyColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("NotifyColor", typeof(Color), typeof(VirtualizingNotifyTextBlock), new PropertyMetadata(Colors.Red));

    public Color NotifyColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(NotifyColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NotifyColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public int NotifyDuration
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(NotifyDurationProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NotifyDurationProperty, value); }
    }

    public int NotifyRepeat
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(NotifyRepeatProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NotifyRepeatProperty, value); }
    }

    public INotifyPropertyChanged DataItem
    {
        get { return _dataItem; }
        set
        {
            if (_dataItem != null)
            {
                Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
                _dataItem.PropertyChanged -= DataItem_PropertyChanged;
            }
            _dataItem = value;
            if (_dataItem != null)
            {
                _dataItem.PropertyChanged += DataItem_PropertyChanged;
            }
        }
    }

    private void NotifyTextBlock_TargetUpdated(object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e)
    {
        var binding = this.GetBindingExpression(VirtualizingNotifyTextBlock.TextProperty);
        if (binding != null)
        {
            _propertyName = binding.ResolvedSourcePropertyName;
            DataItem = binding.DataItem as INotifyPropertyChanged;
        }
    }

    private void DataItem_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == _propertyName)
        {
           var animation = new ColorAnimation(NotifyColor, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(NotifyDuration)));
           animation.RepeatBehavior = new RepeatBehavior(NotifyRepeat);
           animation.AutoReverse = true;
           Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
           Background.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, animation);
        }
    }

}
```

Xaml:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="readOnlyCellUpdatedStyle">
    <local:VirtualizingNotifyTextBlock Text="{Binding KeyIndex, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" NotifyColor="Blue" NotifyDuration="250" NotifyRepeat="4" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Dude, thanks a lot for taking time to answer, it is most appreciated. I am doing/learning through doing this WPF/MVVM app in my own time. I will try this tonight and accept in due course.